# Can't i make multiple returns using if statements?

Tags: typescript, bun

Here is my code:

```js
const server = Bun.serve({
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 8080,
    fetch: handler, 
});

console.log(`Listening on http://${server.hostname}:${server.port}`)

function handler(request: Request): Response {
    const url = new URL(request.url)

    if (url.pathname === '' || url.pathname === '/')
        return new Response(Bun.file("index.html"))
    
    return new Response("Not Found", {status: 404})


}
```

Here is the issue:

`function handler(request: Request): Response (+1 overload)`

Thank you

I tried to make sure wrong links gives 404

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need `{}` curly braces if you want to do a `return`

```
function handler(request: Request): Response {
    const url = new URL(request.url)

    if (url.pathname === '' || url.pathname === '/') {
        return new Response(Bun.file("index.html"))
    }

    return new Response("Not Found", {status: 404})


}
```